# Twisted, only process latest request while terminating previous ones

Tags: python, twisted

Im trying to setup a twisted project that runs a terminal command and returns output on completion.  However when a client starts a request on port 9000 for example, twisted will block all other requests on that port and process them once the initial request is done.

Is it possible for twisted to terminate all previous requests and only run the latest request?

EDIT:

Ive tried the following:
`

```
def _query(script):
    d = utils.getProcessOutput('/bin/sh', script)
    def _parse(output):
        return output
    d.addCallback(_parse)
    return d

output = _query('script.sh')
print output
```

However I just get a deferred object when printing output.   The script can take time to complete, however it doesnt seem to wait as long as it should.

Comment: Twisted doesn't do any of this stuff.  Your program does, perhaps using Twisted.  Share your program, ideally minimized to exclude extraneous details (see http://sscce.org/), or all anyone can do is make wild guesses about what's going on.

Comment: Ive updated my original question, with a better example as to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
output = _query('script.sh')
print output
```

Since `_query` returns a `Deferred`, this doesn't do what you want.  You want the output of running the script which is available as the result of the `Deferred`.  The purpose of `Deferred` is to make results available to your code *when they become available*.  To do this, you attach callbacks to the `Deferred`.  There's an example of this earlier in your code:

```
def _parse(output):
    return output
d.addCallback(_parse)
```

but this callback doesn't do anything (that is, you could delete these three lines and not change the behavior of the program).

Instead, what you want to do is attach a callback that processes the script output in some way.  Since you attached the `flask` tag to the question, I suppose you have a flask web server and you want this code to run when a request is received, then produce the script output in the response to that request.

Flask assumes a blocking paradigm, with concurrency achieved either through multithreading or multiprocessing.  It will be moderately challenging to use Twisted in this context to do what you want.  It is possible (for example, with [Crochet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crochet)) but it's not clear it's particularly beneficial.

You may want to consider replacing Flask with [Klein](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/klein) or replacing Twisted with some standard blocking library calls.